# IDA: Demangled name simplification in idapython

Tags: ida, c++, idapython, idapro-sdk

With idapython I would like to get demangled names with the [name simplification (bottom of page)](https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-35-demangled-names/) applied to them.

For example, the following function:

```shell
Python> ida_name.demangle_name(idc.get_func_name(0x123456), 0)

std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>::vector(void)'
```

As you can see, the function name is very long with all the templates. IDA applies some rules from `goodname.cfg` to simplify this name. In its GUI the following is displayed:

```
std::vector<std::string>::vector(void)
```

Much better. Is there any way to achieve the same result in idapython? Other than copying and applying all the rules from `goodname.cfg` inside my script...

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than re-implementing IDA's filtering. Mangled symbol names as output by compilers always contain full specifications of the symbols, which ignore any typedef or using declarations that make them nice and compact in source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`idaapi.get_ea_name(ea, idaapi.GN_SHORT|idaapi.GN_DEMANGLED)` seems to return the filtered demangled name.

Comment: Oh shit, you are a life saver. Thank you!


edit: `idaapi.get_long_name(ea)` seems to work as well. guess I should have tried all the functions in the idaapi module. lesson learned, thanks